# Is there away to upload a file through RestFUL API PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to develop a RESTFUL API call in PHP , where someone will send me a file through the URL to upload

something like:

```
 script.php?file_name=text.txt
```

is there away I can take text.txt and upload it in PHP?

To clarify:

**lets put it this way , what are the ways that a end user could send a file to a PHP program?**

Comment: so yes or no ? if yes show me an example please

Comment: so basically either the user has to FTP upload the file , or send it through a form?

Comment: A filename sent using the querystring is nothing more than a string containing the filename. There is no way in hell you could make a request to the client to retrieve the file.

Comment: i was thinking of base64 encoding the file and putting it in the url. but i may of missed the point of the question

Comment: The real question is: [what are you trying to do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: God! You know what @Dagon that actually works. (it's a very limited solution) but it works

Comment: I am trying to build an API restful code in PHP to get FILE info from the user , thats basically it ? how could I do that , and can I do it without a FORM submit?

Comment: @PeeHaa How its ganna work?

Comment: If you know what rest is you shouldn't be doing a get either way. Either use a form or use some http client

Comment: yes I have basic understanding but never sent a file through API request before , that's what I am talking about

Comment: basically lets say I have a file test.txt in my C drive , can I send that through a GET or a POST without uploading it manually through a FORM? if YES how can I do that?

Comment: as isaid above all you need to do is base64 encode it and add it just like any other 'field'

Comment: Yes you can send it through a POST. A simple search should give you many examples. Is your goal to have the user be able to click a link on your webpage and it automatically upload a file from their computer, or to knowingly use an api?

Comment: but how my server will know the content of the file supplied?

Comment: @VBCPP I know a simple POST FORM , I think ftp upload is better

Comment: @Dagon one of the ideas of a RESTful API is that it observes many different HTTP methods, you seem to be fixated on GET, probably because there's a filename in the query string - it is **absolutely** feasible to POST the contents of a file to `somefile.php?name=text.txt`. You were right in your very first comment. As far as sending this through GET entirely, you have to observe potential URL querystring length limits (around 2000 characters), and is goes against the principle theory of GET method. You're sending data from the client, so POST everything (name and encoded file contents).

Answer (score -1):

The problem with this is that the REST server is not aware of the end user's machine in any way. So, say for instance that your end user is at yoursite.com/upload where they fill out a form with the upload credentials which posts to api.yoursite.com/uploads/do or whatever. As far as the api is concerned, yoursite.com is making the request, not the end user.

So, no. In my opinion there is no safe way to do this. The best alternative would be to upload the file and then HTTP POST the contents to the rest server. That can be tricky if the file is much larger than a few kilobytes, and you would want to do all sorts of security checking before writing the file to the server. The other option would be to use yoursite.com to upload the file to a temporary location and then send some information to the rest server with details on out to CURL the file contents from the first server. Also, can be insecure.

What problem are you trying to solve? What language framework? Can you give more details please?

Comment: so its either the end user upload the file through a FORM or with FTP credentials they login and upload the files there , these are most secured

Comment: Similar question that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192496/restful-uploading-of-a-file-in-php?rq=1

Comment: But this example asking the end user to write a CURL PHP call with file info

Comment: so the bottom line the server needs to know the location of teh file supplied to get the info from so he can process the upload

Comment: how do you imagine people using your API will interact with it? type in the browser url ?

Comment: If they aren't using a form, how does the user decide which file to upload?

Comment: yes, but the user has to supply it somehow. If not a form, then how? Are they typing the REST URL?

Comment: off a users computer ?!? sure that safe

Comment: @user3150060, please take 10 minutes and  edit your original question add 3 or 4 paragraphs on what your doing, no one is really sure at this point, we will wait :-)

Comment: I agree with Dragon. Without really understanding what you are trying to accomplish, this seems really insecure to me.

Comment: On another note, this was my first answer on Stack Overflow. Is it okay for me to ask why my answer was down voted so I can clarify in the future? If not, that's cool :-)

Comment: im trying to let you guys understand my question maybe just someone list all possible way I can transfer a file or multi files to a server , this might help me

Comment: @user3150060 if you don't want to take the time to explain, i don't want to take the time to help - see how this works ? bye.